# Como fazer o slider não pegar o último elemento?

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber como resolver o seguinte caso.

Tenho uma estrutura da seguinte maneira:

```html
<section class="portfolio slide" id="portfolio">
    <h2>portfólio.</h2>
    <div id="foto">
        <img src="images/img-1.jpeg" alt="imagem 1" />
    </div>
    <div id="foto">
        <img src="images/pexels-photo.jpg" alt="imagem 2" />
    </div>
    <div id="foto">
        <img src="images/img-1.jpeg" alt="imagem 3" />
    </div>
    <div class="botao">
        <a href="#" class="botao-portfolio">
            <i  class="far fa-eye"></i>
            veja mais.
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Eu quero fazer um slider que alterne as fotos nas `<div>` com o `id="foto"`, porém o meu código está "pegando" a `<div>` com a `class="botao"`. Gostaria de saber se é possível não "pegar" última `<div>`. Obrigado!

Segue o código jQuery:

```js
function slider(sliderName) {
    var sliderClass = '.' + sliderName,
        activeClass = 'active';

    $('.slide > #foto:first').addClass('active');

    function rotateSlide() {
        var activeSlide = $(sliderClass + ' > .' + activeClass),
            nextSlide = activeSlide.next();

        if(nextSlide.length == 0) {
            nextSlide = $(sliderClass + ' > :first');
        }
        activeSlide.removeClass(activeClass);
        nextSlide.addClass(activeClass);
    }
}

slider('portfolio');
```

Comment: Matheus, cole como código na pergunta, depois marque com o mouse e aperte o botão { } (ou aperte control K). Ou, acrescente quatro espaços no começo de cada linha de código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar `nextSlide = activeSlide.next('#foto');` dessa forma ao invés de retornar o próximo elemento, sua query só retornará o próximo elemento com id igual a foto.

Só uma observação: Não dê o mesmo id para dois elementos da sua DOM, ids devem ser únicos, isso pode causar vários tipos de erros. Ao invés de ter vários elementos com o id foto, tenha vários elementos com a classe foto, e faça queries usando ".foto" ao invés de "#foto".

Comment: Matheus, aqui a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita (clicando no "sinal de visto", ✓, logo abaixo da seta para baixo), veja essa página: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), e [Por que é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Aproveite também para visitar a [página de boas-vindas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site.